# Cant see shared machine images in project

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm following the [Using Images from Other Projects](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/using-images-from-other-projects-for-vm-instances) guide.
There is a project A in which I am granted compute.imageUser (not owner) and a project B that I own. Project A has a machine image which I want to use in project B to create a virtual machine.

Even after being granted access to them I can't see the machine images under the compute engine tab in the console of Project B.

Has someone experienced something similar to that and would like to help me out?

Thank you

Comment: does the user has like Project Viewer access to Project A? I mean, besides "compute.imageUser"

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you have a proper service account account name bound to the project A. [Here's the step-by-step instruction](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/using-images-from-other-projects-for-vm-instances#granting_access_to_images) how to find a correct service account (it sounds trivial but any misspelled character will result in access denied).

There are some limitations to that (make sure it's not the case):

- You must grant the compute.imageUser role on the project level.
- Granting the compute.imageUser role grants permissions to all images in the specific project. It is not possible to share specific images.
- You must grant this role to specific users, and not to `allAuthenticatedUsers` or `allUsers`.

Furthermore - [you can create your custom image and share it](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/managing-access-custom-images) but you would have to get additional permissions in project A:

- compute.images.create to create new images
- compute.images.list to list images in the project
- compute.disks.use if the image will be created from a disk
- compute.disks.list if you want to grant users the ability to see a list of disks in the project

If you need access to just one or two images the latter solution (sharing custom images) may be best for you.